# Tomato leaves dying

Tags: houseplants, tomatoes

[image][image]
I am located in India and here the whether is around 34 degree with bright sun.
I have tomato plant in my balcony in 2 feet pot. It seems the leaves are dying suddenly. See in attached photo. 
Soil is enough wet in pot as I am regularly watering it.
Suggest if anything I should change.

Comment: How do you water the plant? On more north, on greenhouses in summer, people sprays tiny droplet of water (often, but not too long, not to get fungi disease) in order to cold down the plant. Not sure this is the solution of your problem, but tomatoes have difficulties on hot climate.

Comment: I am watering directly into pot, like in soil only. Should i spray it on leaves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rigging up some shade for it during the hours of 11-3 - your temperatures are pretty hot and the tomato plant is probably struggling if it's in full sun all day. It doesn't look like its dying, but it does look a little wilted, and extensive periods of hot sunshine can cause that.

Comment: Thank you @Bamboo . I checked in evening and I could see the leaves were normal and not wilted. May be the extensive sun is causing this. I will try some shade for it.  But i had one more tomato plant which was in balcony but not direct sunlight. It got yellow leaves and i could see white and black insects , not sure if it was due to shade ?

Comment: If the black and white insects were tiny and winged, they were likely aphids - these suck on the sap of the plant and can cause damage and dieback.

Comment: It did after that. Any suggestion how to prevent it.

Comment: If you mean aphid infestation, it caa't be prevented, only treated - neem oil spray or washing them off with a stream of water,  but they;ll be back the next day, so its an ongoing treatment need.

Comment: I keep washing them with water spray, plant survived for few days than fruits few tomatoes than dies. Also the fruit has been always small. it got ripe in small size only.

Comment: small fruits may be to do with the size of the pot - each tomato plant needs a 9 inch pot all to itself... hard to comment on quite what insects were present on your previous tomato  plant without photographic evidence, aphids was an educated guess

Comment: I dont have picture of tomato plant right now but I do have other plants photo, seems to have same insects.  attaching in question again.

Comment: Better to post it as a separate question - the site would prefer that, it makes it easier for others to find the information.

Comment: I have posted already as this is a different plant. I posted as reference for the insects I was talking about on Tomato. Anyways, thank you for all the comments. It seems I should have only put tomato plants picture not any other as the question is about tomato.and site prefers that.